# Show that $|\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]2))|=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]2)$. Show that $|\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]2))|=2$.

Well, it is easy to see that the degree of this extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is ten. Also, is easy to see that there are two $\mathbb{Q} $-automorphisms, namely the identity and the mapping $\psi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]2) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[10]2)$ determined by $$\sqrt[10]2 \mapsto -\sqrt[10]2.$$
But i can not ensure that there are no more.

Comment: Think about the 10th roots of unity.  Only two of them live in $\mathbb R$.  But $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[10]2)\subseteq \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : an automorphism $\sigma$ is uniquely determined by its value at the generator $\sqrt[10]{2}$, which must be a root of $X^{10}-2$. Which of those roots lay in $\mathbb K$ ?

Comment: I presume only $\sqrt[10]{2}$ and -$\sqrt[10]{2}$ are in $ Q(\sqrt[10]{2})$, but i do not know why...

Comment: @JuniorSoares Your presumption is correct, and Gregory Grant's comment explains why. If $\theta$ is any root of $X^{10}-2$ in $\mathbb K$, then $\alpha=\frac{\theta}{\sqrt[10]{2}}$ is also in $\mathbb K$, and is a tenth root of unity.